# Schema validation errors while parsing:Invalid xsi:type qname

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, weblogic, weblogic12c

we have one java application which running currently on weblogic 10.
we need to deploy this application to weblogic 12.2.1.2.
So I have created one weblogic domain in weblogic 12.2.1.2 and I made change in config.xml file according to config.xml which we already have for weblogic 10.

server and java combination we are using:

1. weblogic 10 + jrockit_160_05(java)
2. weblogic 12.2.1 + java 8

When we start server I getting many error.see the below log.

```
<24-May-2017, 10:52:39,491 AM IST> <Info> <Security> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <main> <> <> <> <1495603359491> <[severity-value: 64] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.> 
<24-May-2017, 10:52:39,571 AM IST> <Info> <Security> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <main> <> <> <> <1495603359571> <[severity-value: 64] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to HMACDRBG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:39,915 AM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603359915> <[severity-value: 64] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 25.131-b11 from Oracle Corporation.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:40,29 AM IST> <Info> <RCM> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-9> <> <> <> <1495603360029> <[severity-value: 64] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-2165021> <"ResourceManagement" is not enabled in this JVM. Enable "ResourceManagement" to use the WebLogic Server "Resource Consumption Management" feature. To enable "ResourceManagement", you must specify the following JVM options in the WebLogic Server instance in which the JVM runs: -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+ResourceManagement.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:40,257 AM IST> <Info> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603360257> <[severity-value: 64] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 12.2.1.2.0 Mon Oct  3 04:35:36 PDT 2016 1827450>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:40,264 AM IST> <Warning> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603360264> <[severity-value: 16] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141274> <Production mode has been specified at the command line using the the weblogic.ProductionModeEnabled system property. This system property overrides the development mode setting contained in the config.xml file. However, the Administration Console and WLST show the attribute values and defaults that correspond to the development mode specified in the config.xml file.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,788 AM IST> <Warning> <JMSExceptions> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361788> <[severity-value: 16] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-045142> <WebLogic Server has detected a deprecated JMS Interop Module in your configuration. This feature will be removed in a future release. Oracle recommends that you take appropriate measures to remove dependencies on JMS Interop Modules.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,940 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361940> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml<8:7> - Invalid xsi:type qname: 'wls:realm-adapter-authenticatorType' in element realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,940 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361940> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml - C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\<unknown>:8:7: error: failed to load java type corresponding to t=realm-adapter-authenticatorType@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,942 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361942> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml<12:7> - Invalid xsi:type qname: 'wls:realm-adapter-authorizerType' in element realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,942 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361942> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml - C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\<unknown>:12:7: error: failed to load java type corresponding to t=realm-adapter-authorizerType@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,942 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361942> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml<14:7> - Invalid xsi:type qname: 'wls:realm-adapter-adjudicatorType' in element realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,943 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361943> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml - C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\<unknown>:14:7: error: failed to load java type corresponding to t=realm-adapter-adjudicatorType@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,943 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361943> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml<18:7> - Expected elements 'user-lockout-manager@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deploy-role-ignored@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deploy-policy-ignored@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deploy-credential-mapping-ignored@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security fully-delegate-authorization@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security validate-dd-security-data@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security security-dd-model@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security combined-role-mapping-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security enable-web-logic-principal-validator-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security max-web-logic-principals-in-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security delegate-m-bean-authorization@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security auth-methods@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security compatibility-object-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security rdbms-security-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security password-validator@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deployable-provider-synchronization-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deployable-provider-synchronization-timeout@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security auto-restart-on-non-dynamic-changes@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security retire-timeout-seconds@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security management-identity-domain@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security' instead of 'key-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security' here in element realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,943 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361943> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml<43:7> - Expected elements 'user-lockout-manager@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deploy-role-ignored@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deploy-policy-ignored@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deploy-credential-mapping-ignored@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security fully-delegate-authorization@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security validate-dd-security-data@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security security-dd-model@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security combined-role-mapping-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security enable-web-logic-principal-validator-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security max-web-logic-principals-in-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security delegate-m-bean-authorization@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security auth-methods@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security compatibility-object-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security rdbms-security-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security password-validator@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deployable-provider-synchronization-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security deployable-provider-synchronization-timeout@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security auto-restart-on-non-dynamic-changes@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security retire-timeout-seconds@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security management-identity-domain@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security' instead of 'key-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security' here in element realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.>
<24-May-2017, 10:52:41,944 AM IST> <Error> <Management> <BSOLDHN-020> <> <Thread-5> <> <> <> <1495603361944> <[severity-value: 8] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\OSLChOpsDomain\config\config.xml<58:3> - Expected elements 'jta@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jpa@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain deployment-configuration@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain wtc-server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain log@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain snmp-agent@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain snmp-agent-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain root-directory@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain console-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain java-service-console-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain console-context-path@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain console-extension-directory@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain server-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain coherence-server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain cluster@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain file-t3@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain messaging-bridge@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain production-mode-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain embedded-ldap@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain administration-port-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain administration-port@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain exalogic-optimizations-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain java-service-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain archive-configuration-count@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain config-backup-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain configuration-version@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain administration-m-bean-auditing-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain configuration-audit-type@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain cluster-constraints-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain app-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain library@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain domain-library@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ws-reliable-delivery-policy@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain machine@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-entity-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-registry@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain virtual-host@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain virtual-target@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain migratable-target@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ejb-container@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain web-app-container@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain cdi-container@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jmx@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain self-tuning@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain resource-management@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain path-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-bridge-destination@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain bridge-destination@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain shutdown-class@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain startup-class@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain singleton-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain mail-session@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jolt-connection-pool@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain log-filter@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain file-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain replicated-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jdbc-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-interop-module@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-system-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain custom-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain foreign-jndi-provider@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain admin-server-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain administration-protocol@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain wldf-system-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jdbc-system-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain saf-agent@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain migratable-rmi-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain webservice-security@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-connection-consumer@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain auto-deploy-for-submodules-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain admin-console@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain internal-apps-deploy-on-demand-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain guardian-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ocm-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain msg-id-prefix-compatibility-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain log-format-compatibility-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain coherence-cluster-system-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain restful-management-services@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain system-component@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain system-component-configuration@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain osgi-framework@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain webservice-testpage@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain server-migration-history-size@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain service-migration-history-size@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain coherence-management-cluster@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain partition@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain partition-uri-space@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain resource-group@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain resource-group-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain max-concurrent-new-threads@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain max-concurrent-long-running-requests@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain parallel-deploy-applications@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain parallel-deploy-application-modules@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-executor-service-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-scheduled-executor-service-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-thread-factory-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-executor-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-scheduled-executor-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-thread-factory@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue I have inserted one below line of code in startWeblogic.cmd file.

set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.configuration.schemaValidationEnabled=false